# Returning multiple items with Servlet

Tags: file, servlets, download

Good day, I'm working on a Servlet that must return a PDF file and the message log for the processing done with that file.

So far I'm passing a boolean which I evaluate and return either the log or the file, depending on the user selection, as follows:

```
            //If user Checked the Download PDF
        if (isDownload) {
            byte[] oContent = lel;
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.pdf");
            out = response.getOutputStream();
            out.write(oContent);
        } //If user Unchecked Download PDF and only wants to see logs
        else {
            System.out.println("idCompany: "+company);
            System.out.println("code: "+code);
            System.out.println("date: "+dateValid);
            System.out.println("account: "+acct);
            System.out.println("documentType: "+type);

            String result = readFile("/home/gianksp/Desktop/Documentos/Logs/log.txt");
            System.setOut(System.out);

            // Get the printwriter object from response to write the required json object to the output stream      
            PrintWriter outl = response.getWriter();
            // Assuming your json object is **jsonObject**, perform the following, it will return your json object  
            outl.print(result);
            outl.flush();
        }
```

Is there an efficient way to return both items at the same time?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

HTTP protocol doesn't allow you to send more than one HTTP response per one HTTP request. With this restriction in mind you can think of the following alternatives:

1. Let client fire two HTTP requests, for example by specifying`onclick` event handler, or, if you returned HTML page in the first response, you could fire another request on `window.load` or `page.ready`;
2. Provide your for an opportunity of choosing what he'd like to download and act in a servlet accordingly: if he chose PDF - return PDF; if he chose text - return text and if he chose both - pack them in an archive and return it.

Note that the first variant is both clumsy and not user friendly and as far as I'm concerned should be avoided at all costs. A page where user controls what he gets is a much better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap them in a DTO object or place them in the session to reference from a JSP.